# In-Place Word/Symbol Dabbrev Expand

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, expansion, abbreviation

Here's my extension to dabbrev-expand to support sub-string expansion.It works as expected, as far as I know. However I would find it even more useful if it supported *in-symbol* expansion similar to the behaviour of `mdabbrev`, which, by the way, is incomplete in terms of symbol-character and case-adjustment support. The `pattern` argument to `dabbrev-substring-search`, however, is only the pattern before point but for in-place expansions we need the pattern after point aswell. Why isn't this pattern available in hippie/dabbrev-expand and is there a preferred way to query it?

```
(defun dabbrev-substring-search (pattern &optional reverse limit syntax-context)
  "Expand dabbrev substring. See:
http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/HippieExpand#toc5"
  (let ((result ())
        (regpat (cond ((not hippie-epxand-dabbrev-as-symbol)
                       (concat (regexp-quote pattern) W*))
                      ;; ((eq (char-syntax (aref pattern 0)) ?_)
                      ;;  (concat (regexp-quote pattern)
                      ;;          "\\(\\sw\\|\\s_\\)*"))
                      (t
                       (concat "\\(?:"
                               Y<
                               "\\(" "\\(?:\\sw\\|\\s_\\)+" "\\)"
                               "\\(" (regexp-quote pattern) "\\)"
                               "\\(" "\\(?:\\sw\\|\\s_\\)*" "\\)"
                               Y>
                               "\\)"

                               "\\|"

                               "\\(?:"
                               Y<
                               "\\(" "\\(?:\\sw\\|\\s_\\)*" "\\)"
                               "\\(" (regexp-quote pattern) "\\)"
                               "\\(" "\\(?:\\sw\\|\\s_\\)+" "\\)"
                               Y>
                               "\\)"

                               )))))
    (while (and (not result)
                (if reverse
                    (re-search-backward regpat limit t)
                  (re-search-forward regpat limit t)))
      (setq result (buffer-substring-no-properties (save-excursion
                                                     (goto-char (match-beginning 0))
                                                     ;;(skip-syntax-backward "w_")
                                                     (point))
                                                   (match-end 0)))

      (if (he-string-member result he-tried-table t)
          (setq result nil)))     ; ignore if bad prefix or already in table

    (when nil
      (when result
        (let* ((p (point))
               (end3 (match-end 3))
               (beg2 (match-end 2))
               (end2 (match-end 2))
               (dummy (message "%s %s %s" end3 beg2 end2))
               (beg (- end3 beg2))       ;begin offset from point
               (end (- end3 end2)))      ;end offset from point
          (setq dabbrev-substring-match-region (cons beg end))
          (hictx-generic (- p beg) (- p end) nil 'match 3))))

    result))
;; Use: (dabbrev-substring-search "he")

(defun try-expand-dabbrev-substring-visible (old)
  "Like `try-expand-dabbrev' but for visible part of buffer."
  (interactive "P")
  (let ((old-fun (symbol-function 'he-dabbrev-search)))
    (fset 'he-dabbrev-search (symbol-function 'dabbrev-substring-search))
    (unwind-protect (try-expand-dabbrev-visible old)
      (fset 'he-dabbrev-search old-fun))))

(defun try-expand-dabbrev-substring (old)
  "Like `try-expand-dabbrev' but for substring match."
  (interactive "P")
  (let ((old-fun (symbol-function 'he-dabbrev-search)))
    (fset 'he-dabbrev-search (symbol-function 'dabbrev-substring-search))
    (unwind-protect (try-expand-dabbrev old)
      (fset 'he-dabbrev-search old-fun))))

(defun try-expand-dabbrev-substring-all-buffers (old)
  "Like `try-expand-dabbrev-all-buffers' but for substring match."
  (interactive "P")
  (let ((old-fun (symbol-function 'he-dabbrev-search)))
    (fset 'he-dabbrev-search (symbol-function 'dabbrev-substring-search))
    (unwind-protect (try-expand-dabbrev-all-buffers old)
      (fset 'he-dabbrev-search old-fun))))
```

which is activated for example using

```
(setq hippie-expand-try-functions-list
        (append
         '(
           try-expand-dabbrev-substring-visible
           try-expand-dabbrev-substring
           try-expand-dabbrev-substring-all-buffers)))
```

Answer (score 0):

This might or might not help.  Like ordinary dabbrev, it works with the text before point, but candidate matching can be substring, regexp, or fuzzy (various kinds), in addition to prefix.  [Icicles - Dynamic Abbreviation](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Completion_in_Other_Buffers#DynamicAbbreviation)